# What should we do with [diy]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The [diy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diy) (do it yourself, x22) tag covers

- [computer-building](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer-building) in the sense of assembling your own machine
- [repair](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/repair) in the sense of doing the repair yourself

"DIY" alone doesn't really have a purpose. Should we disambiguate it with the above (more specific) tags?

Also, would it make sense to create a synonym for one of these tags?

Comment: If we get rid of the diy tag from these posts, it will not be offered which should mitigate it coming up again. Plus less work in having to create a synonym for a still too ambiguous tag

Comment: At SU it seems that DIY would have to do with hardware solutions, software solutions, network solutions and some programming solutions (macros, batch, etc but I don't see any right now). It'd be difficult to determine what it should be a synonym for, unless it just goes what it's been tagged on most.